# in ios how to align 8*8 icons(images) on UIView when developing zoo keeper game

Tags: objective-c, ios

I've developed the game zoo keeper on java platform. Now I need to make it run on ios, however I am not familiar with xcode and objc. I meet some problems when using `UIView` and `UIImageview`. Say we have 8*8 icons(images) with 5 types, we change two neighbor icons and whenever 3 icons or more are identical on horizontal or vertical line, they would be eliminated and create new icons to replace on previous locations. To implement it in java, i just need to check conditions and delete those eliminated icons and draw new ones(all according to the coordinates) then repainted the JPanel. But how would I implement it in ios? Not say eliminating process, I don't even know how to align those 64 (8*8) icons on the `UIView`. At first I think maybe using the `UIImageview` and then addSubview on one background `UIView`. But if in this way, there would be 64 subviews, it would be totally a mess. I am so new to the xcode and objc, and I have only 2 weeks to finish the task. Can anybody help me to my problem? Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from what I gathered, in Java you just PAINTED the icons inside a JPanels paintComponent?

well you **could do** it totally analog in this case.. place ONE uiview on the screen which acts as your JPanel/Drawing Canvas. In drawRect do your drawing the same way as you did in java

@interface CustomView : UIView 
    @end

```
@implementation CustomView

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)dirtyRect {
    [[UIColor redColor] set];
    for(int ix = 0; ix < ITEMS_PER_ROW; ix++ ) {
        for(int iy = 0; iy < ITEMS_PER_COLUMN; iy++) {
            //draw item at ix and iy
            CGPoint pt = CGPointMake();
            CGRect r = CGRectMake(ix*5;iy*5, 5, 5);
            CGRectFill(r);
        }
    }
}

@end
```

*typed inline, no guarantees ^^

---

**that said, I would go with CALayers**

not drawing it but using 64 sublayers.. well maybe not 64 ... maybe you could group it a bit
=> you'd then have the benefit of implicit animations

Comment: Thanks so much! I love you!!

Answer (score 0):

I just don't see the mess. Yes, you would end up having 64 subviews either way on your background `UIView`.

If it is more easy or logical for you then you could create and position the `UIImageViews` only once and later just change their `UIImage`. The `UIImage`, which holds the icon itself, is just a property of an `UIImageView` while the `UIImageView` is part of the view hierarchy and has coordinates and sizes or a frame etc.

If you really hussle with the 64 individual view objects: Depending on how your logic works on the java side it may appear more logical and therefore more easy to you to acutally draw only one image using core data. That one image would be made of the 8x8 icons and would be re-drawn on every change. Your `UIImageView` would then simply fill up all of the underlying `UIView`. (Stricty spoken there would probably no need for an underlying UIView any more in that case because your `UIImageView` coud serve as the `self.view` object of the view controller. But I would still go for a UIView just to apply the usual pattern consistently. )

However, if I were you I would go for a 'fix' grid of `UIImageViews` and just exchange their `UIImage` objects accordingly.